# What does it mean that no casting is possible with templates?

Tags: c++, templates

Templates used as a general code for general types .However , what does it mean that 
a template takes no casting ?

Given the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
T max(T a,T b) {
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}

int main() {
    int i = 2;
    double x = 6.7;
    cout << "The maximum of " << x << " and " << i << 
    " is " << max<double>(i,x) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

What kind of casting can't I do ?

thanks ,Ronen

Comment: What does "a template takes no casting" mean? Where did you read it?

Comment: Can you explain your question more clearly?  This code compiles fine, as long as you disambiguate the overload with std::max (e.g., by calling "::max<double>(i,x)").  The compiler has no problem implicitly converting the int value to double.

Comment: I'm reading a slide of the lecturer of a c++ course , and the following is written : "The guidelines we showed in template 
functions still apply:
 The template class must be included in the file that 
uses it.
 For each “class T”, only one type can be used when 
calling the function ,hence,  no casting.
 More than one general type can be defined. For 
example: template<class T, class G>"

Comment: If you remove 'using namespace std;` (and explicitly use `std::cout`) or specify `::max<double>(i,x)` this code compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: "_only one type can be used when calling the function ,hence, no casting_" maybe they meant _no casting was needed_ (as is the case) as opposed to _no casting is possible_ as you understood?!

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this:

```
int i = 2;
double x = 6.7;
max(i,x);
```

Because the compiler will infer the types to be `int&` and `double&` respectively, and there is no overload of that function that matches. The existing template requires two arguments with the same type.

However, if you do this:

```
max<double>(i,x);
```

You're telling the compiler explicitly that you want to call the specialization of `max` that takes two doubles. Because of this, the compiler will add an implicit conversion from int to double for the first argument. It's this conversion that cannot happen in the first example.

If max was declared like this instead:

```
template<class T, class U>
T max(T a,U b) {
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}
```

You could do `max(i,x)` again, because now it can take arguments of two different types. You would have the problem that the return type would always be that of the first argument, though, which could be undesirable.

Using some features of the new C++11 standard you can have the compiler guess the return type with something more advanced:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class U>
typename std::common_type<T,U>::type max(T a,U b)  {
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}
```

Comment: That was my initial thought as well but I didn't check it. It was pointed out to me that ints are implicitly converted to doubles. His code is fine and would work except for the 'using namespace std` which causes a conflict with `std::max`.

Comment: @Brian: Does `<iostream>` declare `std::max`?

Comment: Do you mean "specialization" or "instantiation"?

Comment: @Kerrek: specialization. Every time you instantiate a template a specialization is generated. You're probably thinking of "explicit specialization" which is when you write a specialization with different code from the primary template. We C++ programmers usually mix these up in conversation.

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles and runs just fine if you call

`::max<double>(i,x)`

or remove `using namespace std;` and explicitly call `std::cout`

or ... don't overload that function.

```
broach@dkc-dadp01:~> g++ -o test test.cc
broach@dkc-dadp01:~> ./test
The maximum of 6.7 and 2 is 6.7
```

`template <class T> const T& max ( const T& a, const T& b );` already exists, and is included when you do `#include <iostream>` (at least in the gcc I'm using). Since you're doing `using namespace std;` your function is ambiguous and this won't compile.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/